# Why client do socket binding in connection oriented communication and not in connection less communication

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, udp

I was brushing up my sockte programming knowledge and came across a doubt.

First let me explain my understanding of sockets.

1. Socket binding associates the socket with port.
2. Socket binding helps kernel to identify the process to whom it should forward the incoming packet.

In connection oriented communication socket establishment is as below

- At server side 
      socket()-->bind()-->listen()-->accept().....
- client side is 
      socket()-->connect-->......

My question is why client need not bind to a socket. In client case if it send a request it has to get a response to its socket and kernel has to forward it to its process.For these things to happen isn't binding needed?If not how kernel will understand to whom to send the response packet?
Also in connection less client call bind socket.Why is it needed here?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is why client need not bind to a socket.

Because the kernel does the bind automatically when you call `connect()`, if you haven't bound the socket yourself.

> Also in connectionless client call bind socket. Why is it needed here?

Because otherwise the socket isn't bound to an IP address:port, so it can't send or receive anything. It has no path to the outside world.

Answer (score -1):

You always open a socket first. This is the path through the kernel. The `connect` call for say TCP happens after the socket is made.

Look at TCP versus UDP clients.

TCP

```
s  = socket(options....)
connect(s)
send(s, data)
```

UDP

```
s = socket(options....)
send(s, data)
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

`bind("0.0.0.0", 0)` (all interfaces, any port) is implicit if you call `connect(...)` or `listen(...)` without an explicit `bind(...)`.

All sockets must be bound to a local port even when connectionless so that bi-directional communication is possible (even if you're not going to do so).

Comment: `connect()` does not cause a bind to 0.0.0.0. It causes a bind to whatever IP address is required to route to the target.